# How to install albert keyboard launcher?

Tags: albert

I want to install a launcher similar to what i had in macOS that can search for files and folders and do various things, this is a far better way of navigating the file system instead of searching for files manually. I know a launcher called Albert exists but i have no idea how to install it, the instructions on their website are pretty much gibberish as a new Linux user.

Any help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, as a new linux user, you should understand that and how most Linux Distributions deliver their software using repositories and also that not all of them do, and some just deliver source code. But to keep it simple assume the most prevalent case: compiled and packaged software delivery via central repositories. This topic is beyond the scope of this question and you will find plenty of information when you just google it.

How you will get albert on your system depends on your preferences. You have (at least) the following options:

#### 1. Use the official repositories of your operating system to install albert.

This is the most **convenient option**. If the package exists you can simply install it. Emphasisis is on *if*. Unfortunately most distributions don't ship albert or often the package is pretty outdated. Still if you are new to linux and are not keen on bleeding edge software, this is the way to go. If you are or your distro does not ship albert you can also …

#### 2. Add the official albert repo sources to your package manager and install it.

This is the **recommended option**, for the average user. Bleeding edge on most platforms with least effort. Unfortunately there *is* some effort you have to go through. But it is just *slightly* more involved than a oneliner.

**tl;dr:** Add the key, add the repo and install albert using your package manager. Keep in mind that the key has an expiration date.

Overview: The [Open Build Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Build_Service) is a platform designed to compile packages for multiple Linux distributions and simplifies the packaging process, so developers can more easily package a single program for many distributions. Whenever GitHub receives a tag, a webhook starts the compilation, packaging and publishing several distributions on OBS. Finally the albert package is public in the repos of OBS. To receive albert from OBS you have to add one of these repos to the sources list of your package manager and trust the key of the platform, which is used to sign the packages. This process is described in the [docs](https://albertlauncher.github.io/installing/#offical-albert-repository--opensuse-build-service).

Example for Ubuntu 20.04:

```bsh
curl https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:manuelschneid3r/public_key | sudo apt-key add -
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_20.04/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:manuelschneid3r.list
sudo wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_20.04/Release.key -O "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:manuelschneid3r.asc"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install albert
```

Example for Fedora 32:

```bsh
sudo rpm --import https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:manuelschneid3r/public_key
dnf config-manager --add-repo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:manuelschneid3r/Fedora_32/home:manuelschneid3r.repo
dnf install albert
```

#### 3. Get precompiled binaries/packages and install them on your system.

This is an option if you do not want to get rolling updates, but stay with a particular version instead. People often recommend this way to install albert, but personally I don't see any reason for this way. It's just here for completeness. You will find the packages on [OBS](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:manuelschneid3r&package=albert).

#### 4. Get the source, get the dependencies, compile it, install it.

This is absolute pro stuff, if you are able you know what to do. Further find some infos [here](https://albertlauncher.github.io/installing/#building-from-sources).

<sub>Note: I am the author of this app. This Q&A is part of the migration of the FAQ to the public.</sub>